# How to go back main screen when user logout app from any screen?

Tags: java, android

When i logout my app (press logout menu button)  from second activity, then it redirect to login page but when i pressed back button again show second screen Activity, it should be goto main screen on back pressed, because i use finish() method but still not go to main screen. then what i do?
Here is my code.

```
      @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second_adapter, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.logout_sec_Act) {
        session.logoutUser();
        finish();
        Toast.makeText(Second_activity.this, "Logout...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    } 


    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: You have to manage your stack. Trigger an intent to go back to the main activity, add the flags to start a clear to a new task, start the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your previous activity is still in the back stack of your task. One way to solve it is by moving to a new empty task when you logout, something like this:

```
Intent logoutIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
logoutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(logoutIntent);
```